# Is it possible to concatenate a string value and a list of objects in terraform

Tags: list, terraform, concatenation

Below is my terraform code where I have a list of objects which has 5 values, is it possible to concat each value in the list with the string values

```
locals{
mylist = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"]
str1 = "hello"
str2 = "Data"

mergedstring =  "${local.str1},local.mylist,${local.str2}"
}
```

I need the output in the following format

```
hello,aaa,Data
hello,bbb,Data
hello,ccc,Data
hello,ddd,Data
hello,eee,Data
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
locals{
  mylist = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"]
  str1 = "hello"
  str2 = "Data"

  mergedstring = join("\n",[for v in local.mylist: "${local.str1},${v},${local.str2}"])
}
```